# Structuring Multiple Wordpress Web Sites

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

Background:
I want to create several Wordpress sites. Each site will primarily be a blog, and I'd like for all of them to have the same look and feel, aside from the content, color scheme, and title. All of the domain names have been leased.

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to easily manage multiple web sites like this. I believe Wordpress can provide a single dashboard for multiple websites, but only for sub-domains. I don't want to misspeak, please correct me if I'm wrong. I do not have an issue with sub-domains, however I would need to make sure that all of the domain names I have leased will redirect properly to the appropriate sub-domain. I also worry about using sub-domains because from what I understand, I'd have to put multiple wordpress config files under the same filesystem and that makes me nervous because that's a single-point-of-failure.

I am not a web developer or linux developer by any means. I'm a network engineer trying to start a side hustle and I've always dabbled with linux and I'd like to do some web hosting for fun and to build a different skill set.

I also want to make sure that from the user's perspective, it isn't complicated to get to these sites. Also, does anyone recommend a hosting platform? I'm currently looking at DigitalOcean. I'd like something that will give me control over the server (IaaS) but at an affordable price.

Questions:
How can I structure these sites?
Does anyone have a recommended hosting platform?

Comment: WordPress has a very specific thing called _Multisite_, is this what you are talking about? If, [you absolutely can use custom domains](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/) and are *not* restricted to just subdomains or folders. I will caution you that Multisite is only really meant to ease admin (and signin) burden. Out of the box, every site is independent of each other, and there's no "cross talk" between sites without custom code. But using Multisite does allow you to have just one config and database, so management is simplified.

Comment: Hosting-wise, whatever you are comfortable with. DigitalOcean is great along with dozens of others. There's some really nice managed hosting out there, too.